# Can you place two Buddha statues on the same turn?

Tags: ghost-stories

In Ghost Stories, players are Buddhist monks trying to stave off invading ghosts before yielding to their (nigh-inevitable) deaths. Each monk chooses one of two similar special abilities at the beginning of the game. The Blue Monk has the potential to make the same action twice in one turn - using a villager twice, or exorcizing ghosts twice.

The Buddhist Shrine, when you use it, lets you pick up a Buddha statue, which you can place on a future turn to instantly kill a ghost that arrives there. The rules seem to assume that you will only have one Buddha statue at a time, and only place one at a time, but the Blue Monk can easily pick up two statues in one turn.

**Can a Blue Monk carrying two statues place both of them on the same turn, in different ghost locations, if they're standing at a corner of the village?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, even if you're not the blue monk (if, for example, you picked up the statues on different turns). From the [rulebook](http://rprod.com/uploads/GS_RULES_US_ver1_3-web.pdf), pages 6-7:

> It may be possible to place two Buddha’s in the same turn, when the Taoist stands on a corner tile and the two corresponding ghost spaces are free.